# Not able to make a HTML visible in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML div that whose visibility i have set to hidden like this ..

```
<div id="checkinuserform" style=" margin:20px; visibility:hidden;">
</div>
```

Now at specific point i want to show this div ..For this i have added following code in jquery ...

```
 var content = $("#checkinuserform").clone().show();
```

BUT , I am not able to see the DIV .Also ,adding clone function is mandatory for me in this case..

Please help me ..
Thanks..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Don't forget to change the ID after you clone it. You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: I think he is replacing the element after he has done someting with the clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
   visibility:none
```

with

```
display:none;
```

Comment: You missed the little detail that the cloned element was not actually added to the DOM. Show will work for `visibility` too.

Comment: How will it help with not included to page cloned element?

Answer (score 4):

When you clone an element, you get a duplicate of it *in a variable*. It won't be visible until you put it somewhere in the page.

Additionally, `show()` doesn't affect `visibility`. Either change the default style to `display: none` or replace `show()` with `.css({visibility: "visible"})`

Comment: Also the ID is duplicated making the HTML invalid, so must be sorted out too.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie actually it might not be a problem , he might need to clone it to do some changes and replace the cloned div

Comment: Thanks for adding my answer to your post!, after all the downvotes I got at first (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 var content = $("#checkinuserform").clone().css('visibility','visible');
```

Fiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/2f7yctmn/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can user css to make it visible instead of clone, try this line of code

```
var content = $("#checkinuserform").css('visibility','visible');
```

but if clone function is mandatory for you, you can write this code

```
var content = $("#checkinuserform").clone();
content.css('visibility','visible');
```

I think this could help